# UMVUE as an optimization problem

Tags: st.statistics, oc.optimization-and-control

Finding UMVUE (Minimum-variance unbiased estimator) looks like an optimisation problem (minimise the variance of $\hat{\theta}$ given the constraint $\text{E}_\theta\hat{\theta}=\theta.$

I tried to apply here a standard method from optimisation but failed.
The setting: $(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ are i.i.d. random variables on the space $(\Omega,F, \mu)$ and $\rho_\theta \mu$ is the measure corresponding to the parameter $\theta.$
Let’s consider a functional
$$
L:= \int_{\Omega}\hat{\theta}^2(X_1,\dots,X_n)\rho_\theta\mu - \left(\int_{\Omega}\hat{\theta}(X_1,\dots,X_n)\rho_\theta\mu \right)^2 - 
\lambda \left( \int_{\Omega}\hat{\theta}(X_1,\dots,X_n)\rho_\theta\mu - \theta
\right )
$$
where $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier corresponding to the constraint $\int_{\Omega}\hat{\theta}(X_1,\dots,X_n)\rho_\theta\mu = \theta.$ Notice that the second term is simple $\theta^2.$

Next we take a functional derivative with respect to $\hat{\theta}.$ The result (with simplified notation) is

$$
\frac{\delta L}{\delta \hat{\theta}} = 2 \int_{\Omega}\hat{\theta} \delta \hat{\theta}\rho_\theta\mu - 0 - \lambda \int_{\Omega}\delta \hat{\theta}\rho_\theta\mu =  \int_{\Omega}(2\hat{\theta}-\lambda) \delta \hat{\theta}\rho_\theta\mu.
$$
So $\frac{\delta L}{\delta \hat{\theta}}=0$ is equivalent to $2\hat{\theta}=\lambda.$ That implies (as I understand) that $\hat{\theta}$ is a constant estimator. This answer doesn’t make any sense to me.

Is it possible to modify this computation somehow in order to get something meaningful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\th\theta$

1. It is not true in general that the Cramér--Rao lower bound is a solution to a meaningful optimisation problem:  ["Under some regularity conditions, the Cramér-Rao lower bound is
   attained iff $f_\th$ is in an exponential family" (p.14)](https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Eshao/stat709/stat709-17.pdf), where $(f_\th)_{\th\in I}$ is a parametric family defining the statistical model and $I$ is an open interval on the real line. In fact, an important condition is missing in this quote: if the Cramér--Rao lower bound is attained for an unbiased estimator $T(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ of $\th$, then, under certain regularity conditions, the joint density of the sample $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ must be of the following specific form
   $$f_\th(x_1,\dots,x_n)
   =\exp[w(\th)T(x_1,\dots,x_n)]
   c(\th)h(x_1,\dots,x_n),$$
   with the same function $T$ in the exponent. So, in most cases the Cramér--Rao lower bound will not be attained.
2. You cannot define an estimator $\hat\theta$ by the formula $\hat\theta(X_1,\dots,X_n):=\th$ -- because an estimator of $\th$ cannot depend on $\th$; it may depend only on the sample $X_1,\dots,X_n$.

Comment: 1. I see, thanks.
2. I understand but I think it should be possible to formulate a meaningful opt. problem even if there is no (in general) solution to it. I don’t know to forbid a constant estimator.

Comment: @Ilia : The problem is that, even when a uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator exists, the Cramér--Rao lower bound is usually not attained at such an estimator. This fact is found in any more or less decent textbook on mathematical statistics. Given this fact, I am wondering what your hope for "a meaningful opt. problem" is based on.

Comment: Right, given this fact my question sound a bit stupid. But I don’t care about the bound itself. Let’s say we just consider the problem to find UMVUE. It is basically the optimisation problem I am taking about. The only problem is that mathematically it looks a bit different from what I am used to. In particular, a constant estimator looks like a mathematically correct solution, and that is absurd.

Comment: @Ilia : So, what is the problem? That the correct solution "looks a bit different from what [you are] used to"?

Comment: Mathematically theta is a parameter. But here an estimator cannot depend on theta. To put it differently, a constant estimator is ‘not allowed’. But how could we express it more formally? For example, it seems like Lagrange multipliers method does’t work here (leads to a constant estimator).

Comment: @Ilia : What you call "a constant estimator" is apparently what is defined by the formula $\hat\theta(X_1,\dots,X_n):=\th$. As I said, this is not an estimator at all, -- because an estimator of $\th$ cannot depend on $\th$; it may depend only on the sample $X_1,\dots,X_n$. Mathematically, given a random sample $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$, where each $X_i$ is a real-valued random variable, a (real-valued) estimator is a random variable of the form $T(X_1,\dots,X_n)$, where $T\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is a Borel-measurable function.

Comment: Previous comment continued: The function $T$ must be the same for all values of $\theta$. E.g., $\bar X:=(X_1+\dots+X_n)/n$ is an estimator, but $\bar X-\theta$ is not an estimator, since it depends on $\theta$. 
This is explained in any decent  textbook on mathematical statistics.

Comment: I realised it is totally unclear what I want to say. Sorry for wasting your time. I completely rewrote the question and added a computation that confused me. Hopefully it is at least clear now what I was trying to do.

Comment: And do you agree with the computation? I don’t understand how to interpret it.

Comment: @Ilia : I did understand what you were doing. You minimize $L$ for each given value of $\theta$. So, your minimizer depends on $\theta$. Therefore, you minimizer is not an estimator. When you restrict the minimization to estimators, you want to "minimize" the entire risk function, which is a function of the estimator and of the parameter $\theta$; you should want to minimize the risk function with respect to the (unbiased) estimator.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Since the risk function (as a function of $\theta$) is in general an inifinite-dimensional vector, such a  "minimization" is not always possible. When it is possible, you get a UMVUE. Of course, your pointwise application of Lagrange multipliers is wrong: again, you want to minimize the risk for all values of $\theta$ at once, not just for one value of $\theta$.

Comment: I see, well, I can’t figure out how to modify the computation to minimize the risk for all values of  at once. So calculus of variations just doesn’t work here?

Comment: @Ilia : No, calculus of variations doesn’t work here, because, as I said, what you want to minimize here (that is, the risk function) is in general an infinite-dimensional vector. In general, even a two-dimensional set (say, a unit disk) does not have a minimum (with respect to the partial coordinate-wise ordering). In a certain class of lucky settings, though, we do have a **uniformly** MVUE -- but the methods to get it are not at all variational.